# has initializer but incomplete type (stuct c++)

Tags: c++, struct

I don't understand what's going on

Util.hpp>>>>>>>>>>

```
#ifndef __UTIL__
    #define __UTIL__

    struct Contact;
    using Contact = struct Contact;
#endif
```

Util.cpp>>>>>>>>>

```
#include "util.hpp"
#include <iostream>

struct Contact
{
    std::string fistname;
    std::string lastname;
    int age;
    std::string number;
};
```

main.cpp>>>>>>>>>>>

```
#include "util.hpp"
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    Contact newContact{"Cage", "Jhonny", 20 ,"+33225254554"};
    return 0;
}
```

compilation result >>>>>>>>>>>>

[image]

I don't understand why there is this error. But everything seems correct

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Why is `using Contact = struct Contact;` necessary? In C++ the `struct` part can be  freely omitted.

Comment: `__UTIL__` is reserved to the implementation; don’t use it for a header-guard macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Contact` is an incomplete type in `main.cpp`.

A declaration like `struct Contact` in `util.hpp` is called a *forward declaration*: you are basically telling the compiler that a struct called Contact will eventually be defined. With just the forward declaration, you can only declare pointers and/or references to `Contact`, since the compiler does not need to know its size for pointers and references.

But to actually declare a variable of type `Contact`, in your `main.cpp`, the compiler needs a complete type, not just the name of something that will eventually exist -- it needs to know what it is. Typically you would fully declare the struct in `Util.hpp` unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: Thank you very much, your clear explanation allowed me to understand and solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

You must put your *entire* `struct` definition in your `util.hpp` file. All you have now is a forward declaration to something that as far as `main.cpp` is concerned, is never fully explained.

In compiler terms, this is an "incomplete type".